# Aligning external elements based on coordinates from a c3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, positioning, c3.js

I'm attempting to do an overlay over a c3 bar chart. I've got the coordinates of the bars and where I wish to place some customization DOM elements but the issue I am running into is that it does align correctly with the bar.

Here is a jsfiddle of my attempt.

```
var label = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("This is 0");
label.style.top = chart.internal.height - chart.internal.x(0) + "px"
label.style.position = "relative";
label.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById("chart").appendChild(label);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cjrobinson/thuwbL96/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needs to be `absolute`positioning  rather than `relative`, after that you'll have to adjust it by a few pixels to vertically centre them in the bar

http://jsfiddle.net/thuwbL96/7/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for cleaning up my horrible code as well. I need to go spend some time learning d3 it seems.